# Validation doesn't fire (System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations)

Tags: c#, validation, attributes, system.componentmodel

I have this class here with 2 properties `Name` and `Age`

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
public class Person
{
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [StringLength(25, MinimumLength = 2)]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Range(0, 100)]
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

and I try to validate the values

```
Person pTemp = new Person();
pTemp.Name = "x"; //invalid because length <2
pTemp.Age = 200; //invalid because > 100
//validation here 
var context = new ValidationContext(pTemp);
var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(pTemp, context, results);
results.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.ErrorMessage));
```

but the only validation attribute that fires is the `[Required]`

where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use another overload:

`var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(pTemp, context, results, true);`

From MSDN:

```
public static bool TryValidateObject(
   Object instance,
   ValidationContext validationContext,
   ICollection<ValidationResult> validationResults,
   bool validateAllProperties
)
```

validateAllProperties
Type: System.Boolean
true to validate all properties; if false, only required attributes are validated..

Since `bool` is equal to `false` by default you have validated only `Required` properties.